# ldap performance issue on client abandon request. possible networking issues

Tags: tcp, ldap

we are trying to investigate performance problems of our LDAP server.
We are moving from an openldap on linux to proprietory (DirX) on windows 2008.

The LDAP is a user store for weblogic applications and configured there as an
Authentication Provider.

Some of the apps are now experiencing performance problems.

Hardware resources are fine and querying the (new) LDAP server using other ldap clients
and via scripts could not reproduce the performance problems.

Then we looked at the network. We found, for the effected applications, a large number of ldap "abandon reqeust" operations eminating from the client. We looked at the behavior with
the original openldap server and found some, but much less 'abandon request' operations.
We don't (yet) know under what circumstances the client decides to send the abandon request.

The scenario below is kind of typical. After the client sends an Abandon Request there
appear a pair of ACKs first the client then the server. and the one sent by ldap takes 0.1 - 0.4 seconds.
And its this delay in the ACK that seems to be costing...

Not being that well versed in the TCP protocol i was hoping for someone to help clarify/confirm my interpretation:

Packet 664 is the ACK from the server to packet 662 (abandon request length 10).
Packet 663 is the ACK from the client to packet 661 (searchResDone)

If my interpretation is correct i would now investigate: 
    - why is the ack to an abandon reqeust taking so long ie 0.20 as opposed to say 0.04
     ( or why is the server taking so long to ack the abandon?)
    - why is the client sending the abandons in the first place?

any other ideas ?

thanks in advance,

Michael

```html
...

657 9.2943 ldapserver ldapclient LDAP 170 searchResDone(57)                                                          
658 9.2948 ldapclient ldapserver TCP 66 18367 > 389 [ACK] Seq=10007 Ack=19799 Len=0  
659 9.2954 ldapclient ldapserver LDAP 1009 searchRequest(134)                             
660 9.2972 ldapserver ldapclient LDAP 630 searchResEntry(134)                             
661 9.2973 ldapserver ldapclient LDAP 172 searchResDone(134)                                    
                                                                Sequence number:45106, len=106
662 9.2978 ldapclient ldapserver LDAP 76 abandonRequest(134)                                                            
                                                                Sequence number: 46818, len=10


663 9.3378 ldapclient ldapserver TCP 66 18368 > 389 [ACK] Seq=46828 Ack=45212 Len=0            
                                                                (The RTT to ACK the segment was: 0.040492000 seconds)
664 9.5062 ldapserver ldapclient TCP 66 389 > 18368 [ACK] Seq=45212 Ack=46828 Len=0         
                                                                (The RTT to ACK the segment was: 0.208397000 seconds)

665 9.5068 ldapclient ldapserver LDAP 183 searchRequest(136)                                 
666 9.5229 ldapserver ldapclient LDAP 163 searchResEntry(136)                                 
667 9.5229 ldapserver ldapclient LDAP 170 searchResDone(136)                                 

....
```